# Difference between citizen and national

Tags: meaning

In a [post](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22525/is-it-true-that-nasa-is-hiring-a-new-planetary-protection-officer) about a NASA position I've read the following (my emphasis):

> The new hire will also receive "secret" security clearance. **Only US citizens and US nationals can apply.**

What is the difference between a "US citizen" and a "US national"? Can there be
a person, who is a US national, but isn't a US citizen or vice versa?

Answer (score -1):

A national has a green card and is a citizen but not born here. Also look up sf-86 requirements since you don't just get a secret clearance given to you it tends to be a pain in the butt.

Comment: To keep it simple and if I'm wrong I'll surely be corrected. If you are born in the United States, it's territories or on a military base on foreign soil you are a naturalized citizen.  Nationals are citizens who were born outside the country but have a legal immigrant status and shall be considered citizens but have certain restrictions such as a president must be born a US citizen. Embassies and military bases are considered sovereign soil but qualify for citizenship